# Initializing Non-pointer Class Members

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, stack, class-members

Lately, I've been reading much about constructors from the well-received [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.22). One of entries mentions that it's always best to use initialization lists, as opposed to initializing class members within the code-block of the constructor itself.

This is because the compiler tends to create multiple copies of the class members, rather than simply one copy.

**Example**

*Good*

```
Foo::Foo( void )
    : mBar( new Bar ) //pointer to some memory address
{
}
```

*Bad*

```
Foo::Foo( void )
{
    mBar = new Bar;
}
```

One thing it also states (and, while this relates to constructors, it also relates to pure initialization of objects in general from even non-member functions ) is that when initializing an object through methods such as the following:

```
void f( void )
{
    Foo foo( Bar() ); //Bad.

    foo.x(); //error
}
```

You will, and I quote: `"[declare] a non-member function that returns a Foo object"`.

(for more info, click the link above)

**The Question**

Because of this, is it unwise to have the following:

```
Geometry::Geometry( void )
    : mFaces( QVector< GLushort >() ),
      mFinalized( false ),
      mNormals( QVector< QVector3D >() ),
      mVerticies( QVector< QVector3D >() )
```

Or even this:

```
Geometry::Geometry( void )
    : mFaces( QVector< GLushort > ),
      mFinalized( false ),
      mNormals( QVector< QVector3D > ),
      mVerticies( QVector< QVector3D > )
```

Because of the way that these are allocated (i.e., the fact that these are non-pointers), it makes me wonder whether or not these objects even NEED initialization in the beginning. If they do, is this the correct method of going about it? Or, is there a better method of initialization?

**How this relates to the question**

This relates to the general question due to the way that the methodology behind C++ constructor initialization relates to both initializing objects using constructor functions, along with the fact that I am ignorant to whether or not objects allocated on the stack - or, so I believe anyway - (either way, objects without pointer allocation) even **need** initialization in the first place.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If a member variable is of a class type with a user-declared default constructor, you do not need to explicitly mention it in the initialization list:  its default constructor will be called anyway, during construction, before the body of the constructor is entered.

If a member variable is a primitive type (like `int` or `bool`) or is of a class type that doesn't have any user-declared constructors, you need to initialize it explicitly, otherwise it will not be initialized (and it will have an unknown value; you cannot read an uninitialized object).

Comment: So, does that mean that, according to the code above, I'm just creating multiple copies of the objects I'm allocating?

Comment: When you use `mFaces( QVector< GLushort >() )`, you construct a temporary `QVector<GLushort>`, copy construct `mFaces` from that temporary object, then destroy that temporary object.  So, yes, you are creating more objects than necessary.